# Error when installing updates to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I tried to install some plugins to my **Eclipse Gallileo**, such as Eclipse **Web Developer Tools** and others. Whatever I try, I get the same error:

```
 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
      session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
      Cannot connect to keystore.
      Uninitialized keystore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in Eclipse concering Eclipse certificates not being trusted by Oracle VM.

From Eclipse FAQ:

> **When I try to install a plug-in, I get a "Cannot connect to keystore." error, what should I do?** [Check](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphical_Eclipse_FAQs#How_do_I_find_out_which_Java_runtime_environment_is_being_used_to_run_my_Eclipse.3F) that you are not using GCJ
>   to run Eclipse. This problem may also surface if you are using IcedTea
>   or an OpenJDK 6 build.
>
> Install Java 6 from Sun and use that to run Eclipse instead.

Comment: Here is what I copied from the box:

java.runtime.name=OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=1.6.0_20-b20
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.specification.version=1.6
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.version=1.6.0_20
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.specification.version=1.0
java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.version=19.0-b09

Answer (score 0):

Solved by upgrading to Indigo.